# Complicated relationship properties on Neo4j database

Tags: php, algorithm, neo4j, cypher, dijkstra

I am developing route planner on Neo4j for education purpose.I developed some algorithm about that and I am using both of cypher query and Rest API in my project.Bu there is a problem which is non-fixed by me.I am trying to calculate different routes from neo4j by the dijkstra, shortestPath and my own algorithm.

For example, There are some nonsense routes that is calculating from neo4j.The output gives many times transfer to another bus to user,When I use dijsktra algorithm in neo4j.Also, it's similarly with shortestPath.I want to give 5 times transfer maximum.How can I prevent that problem?

Also, The neo4j gives the output on the following segment of code;

```
0 => array(
        'Stop' => '1',
        'StopID' => '163',
        'StopName' => 'KALIHI-PALAMA BUS FACILITY',
        'RouteID' => (int) **132**,
        'RouteName' => 'Kalihi via School Street Express',
        'RouteShortName' => 'W3',
        'Relationship' => array(
            'RouteID' => (int) 79,
            'RouteType' => 'ROUTE',
            'EndNode' => '1'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Stop' => '0',
        'StopID' => '4523',
        'StopName' => 'KALIHI TRANSIT CENTER',
        'RouteID' => (int) 1,
        'RouteName' => 'Kaimuki-Kalihi',
        'RouteShortName' => '**132**',
        'Relationship' => array(
            'RouteID' => (int) 1,
            'RouteType' => 'ROUTE',
            'EndNode' => '54'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Stop' => '54',
        'StopID' => '38',
        'StopName' => 'S BERETANIA ST + OPP KALAKAUA AVE',
        'RouteID' => (int) **2**,
        'RouteName' => 'Waikiki-School-Middle',
        'RouteShortName' => '2',
        'Relationship' => array(
            'RouteID' => (int) 2,
            'RouteType' => 'ROUTE',
            'EndNode' => '54'
        )
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'Stop' => '53',
        'StopID' => '37',
        'StopName' => 'KALAKAUA AVE + S KING ST',
        'RouteID' => (int) **132**,
        'RouteName' => 'Waikiki-School-Middle Limited',
        'RouteShortName' => '2L',
        'Relationship' => array(
            'RouteID' => (int) 132,
            'RouteType' => 'ROUTE',
            'EndNode' => '53'
        )
    ) ...
```

It's no sense to giving RouteID=2 Bus.Because, When you are get off the bus, you can get on the same buss again.It's not smarty.How can I prevent this?

I usually use the code in the following segment;

```
START n=node(5), m=node(45)
MATCH p=shortestPath(n-[r:ROUTE*..100]-m)
RETURN p
```

Thanks, Best Regards

Comment: could you share you graph (or a reasonable subset) using http://console.neo4j.org? That would ease up giving a solid answer.

Comment: There is a my demonstration database online.You can check from there in the following segment of code:
http://brain.kaankilic.com:7474/browser

Comment: don't understand your question. Running `START n=node(5), m=node(45)
MATCH p=shortestPath(n-[r:ROUTE*..100]-m)
RETURN extract(r in relationships(p)|r.RouteID)` returns the routeIds along the path: 79, 7, 7, 79, 79, 13. Do you intend to collapse that into 79,7,79,13 ?

Comment: Nop, I dont want collapse that in to 79,79,79,79,7,7,13.
Consider the following;

You are using public transportation reach A point to B point.you are getting on the bus which is 79 number and you are changing the bus in C Station.Do you get on the bus that is 79 number again? Is it sense?

I'm just trying to solve that problem